# like and share facebook error with language

Tags: html, facebook

When i use the share buttons or likebutton
this have a error with language

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcSM.jpg

I read on blogs and forums and tells that this error can be a error with utf-8 
or something

I write in spanish language

Please every help is great

Comment: are you blogger? or you share post from another blog?
may be check your browser....language support option ...
check Spanish language.

Comment: Thanks but this error is for this site only http://goo.gl/sORJE   not for all

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe ...
so, In if its yours website  to include the language option like "locale"..
in your language...

you can use below code also.

[Multi Language](http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Make_Multi_Lingual_Site)

so..You used wordpress ..
Did you install language translate plugin ?
if not then you will find throgh :

```
[WP language Translate][2]
```

Comment: Satyam , I use wordpress not modx? how can do this in that cms?? thanks

Comment: for wordpress ..I edited my ans,..please check it and let me know if you have any query for same.

Answer (score 0):

You must fix the errors here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laeconomista.com%2Fredes-sociales-economia-y-nuevos-negocios-nuevos-paradigmas-de-las-estrategias-empresariales%2F

As you can see the big reason is you're missing the og:locale tag.  And in the og:description the values are messed up too.

Comment: the problem happen with all buttons or share butto  I can fix that with a code or something in my header???

Comment: The problem lies in the HTML of the site being shared.

Comment: You site is still reporting errors that you were told to fix.  Without you fixing them, this issue will continue