# error with facebook share buttons and acent mark

Tags: php, html, facebook, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [like and share facebook error with language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939688/like-and-share-facebook-error-with-language)

with a share button or likebutton in facebook
the site is on spanish language

And the acents mark show very weird with other characters

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcSM.jpg this image show the error

How can fix this??

I try to change the colattion bd language , change the utf8 to iso on wordpress admin panel , and every  tip that I found..

Comment: Have you set the correct charset declaration in the Wordpress template.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are converting between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8.

Try using `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')` to convert the characters.

Comment: now is set with UTF8 i mean... the problem still :(